# Banner to appear after 4 minutes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i created a banner that i want it to appear after 4 minutes.
I use modalbox to show the banner.

i need something like that

```
If customers_session_time > 4 minutes then show me the banner
```

But if i store customers_session_time to the database and write some code on PHP, then the user will have to refresh the page to see the banner.

If i use javascript's setTimeout() the thy timeout period will be refreshed every time the user refreshes the page...

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very complete code, but you may catch an idea

```
<?php
session_start();

if( empty($_SESSION['time_session_started']) ){
    $_SESSION['time_session_started'] = time();
}

$timeout = $_SESSION['time_session_started']+4*60 - time();

if( $timeout<0 ){
    $timeout = 0;
}
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
<?php if( $timeout ){ ?>
setTimeout(function (){
    showBanner();
},<?php echo $timeout*1000; ?>);
<?php }else{ ?>
showBanner();
<?php }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember the timestamp when user requests Your site in session.
Each time the user enters the site You will check if he is here for the first time or when did he came the latest. Then compute time spent already on the site in the session.

```
var timeSpentOnSites = (1000*60*4) - <?= $_SESSION['TIME_SPENT_ALREADY'] ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#banner').show();
  },timeSpentOnSites < 0 ? 0 : timeSpentOnSites);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access any sessions in JavaScript as it is client sided.
What you can do is that AFTER the DOM has been sucessfully loaded you can use the `setTimeout();` method and show the banner after 4 minutes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#banner').show();
},(1000*60*4));

});
```

EDIT: the question was edited after I posted the answer. The answer responds to the first question markup.

Comment: You could access something placed in the page structure at the server side related to the session. Best of both worlds.

Comment: I see.. But if the user refresh the page, the setTimeout will start to count from the beggining?

Comment: sure it does ! I'm not into php so I can only do support for javascript and jquery !